# Sharepoint Attachment Delete File Name

Tags: sharepoint-2007

how to find the attachment filename which is getting deleted

both ItemAttachmentDeleted, ItemAttachmentDeleting events afterproperties and beforeproperties are empty

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 string beforeUrl = properties.BeforeUrl;
 string[] fileName = beforeUrl.Split('/');
 string deletedfile = fileName[fileName.Length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

below code gives us first attachment Name

```
SPFile attachment = properties.ListItem.ParentList.RootFolder.
      SubFolders["Attachments"].SubFolders[properties.ListItemId.ToString()].
      Files[properties.ListItem.Attachments.Count - 1];    

string link =  attachment.Name ;
```